# KeyListener Supposedly Calling upon other Key's code (JDBC)

Tags: java, swing

I have a system so that you can press space to pause the simulation, and then arrows move the camera etc. and then if you press `e`, a JFrame pops up with a JTable inside it with the results from a SQL search of a connected database.

This works fine, I can close the JFrame and carry on running the simulation as usual, all the buttons and functions work.

The problem is after 20 seconds, the system takes the collected data and writes this data to the end of the database, which is fine, that works it writes to the end if the data is not already their. However if I press `e` to open the table, and then close the table, when returning to the simulation screen whatever button I press that has a listener attached to it, will just keep opening new tables, and I am stumped as to the reason why.

Any solution that would allow for when I close this JFrame for my key's to begin to function the way they did before writing to the file, would be greatly appreciated.

Here are the relevant pieces of code (let me know if there is any more you may need)

```
public void databaseConnector(boolean read){
    try{
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/Outputs", "Sam", "sam");
        Statement st = con.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);

        
        String sql = "SELECT INDEX FROM SHM";
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(sql);
        int len = 0;
        while(rs.next()) {
            len++;
        }
        
        if (read){
            databaseReader(st, len);
        } else {
            double data[] = {modulus[0] , natural[0], modulus[1], natural[1], length, startPosition, endPosition, amplitude, equilibrium};
            for (int i = 4; i < data.length; i++){
                data[i] /= 100;
            }  
            PreparedStatement sqls = con.prepareStatement( "SELECT * FROM SHM WHERE " + columnNames[1] + " = " + data[0] + " AND " + columnNames[2] + " = " + data[1] + " AND "
                + columnNames[3] + " = " + data[2] + " AND " + columnNames[4] + " = " + data[3] + " AND "
                + columnNames[5] + " = " + data[4] + " AND " + columnNames[6] + " = " + data[5]);
            databaseWriter(st, len, sqls, data);
        }
        st.close();
        con.close();
    } catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }        
}

public void databaseReader(Statement st, int len){
    try{
        Object[][] data;
                       
        //Get data from table and convert to 2D array
        data = new Object[len][columnNames.length];
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM SHM";
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(sql);
        int x = 0;
        while (rs.next()){
            for(int i = 0; i < columnNames.length; i++){
                data[x][i] = new Double(rs.getDouble(columnNames[i]));
            }                
            x++;
        }
        rs.close();
        //Output data
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Table");
        TableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames);
        JTable table = new JTable(model);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.HIDE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(new JScrollPane(table));
        frame.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        
    } catch (Exception e){
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
public void databaseWriter(Statement st, int len, PreparedStatement sql, double[] data){
    try{
        //checker
                   
        ResultSet rs = sql.executeQuery();
        
        if (!rs.next()){ //if not empty then
            rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM SHM");
            rs.moveToInsertRow();
            rs.updateInt(columnNames[0],len + 1);
            for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                rs.updateDouble(columnNames[i+1],data[i]);
            }
            rs.insertRow();
        }
        rs.close();
        
    } catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    
}



public void gravity(){
    if (moving){
         
        double force = tension();
        Player.ha = force / Player.mass;
        Player.hSpeed += Player.ha * delta / 60;
        //}
        Player.vSpeed += Player.va;
        
        Player.move(1, (int) (Player.hSpeed * delta));
        if (milliSecondTimer < 20){
            calculationChecker();
        }
        if (milliSecondTimer > 20 && !hasWritten){
            endPosition = (int) (maxX - rect.get(0).getMaxX());
            databaseConnector(false);
            hasWritten = true;
        }
    } else {
        milliSecondTimer = 0;
        hasWritten = false;
        amplitude = 0;
        equilibrium = 0;
        MaxX = new  ArrayList<Integer>();
        MinX = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        Equilibrium = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        Player.hSpeed = 0;
        Player.ha = 0;
    }
}



public class MyKeyListener implements KeyListener{

    public void action(){
        int s = 4;
        if (keysDown.contains(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT)){
            s = 10;
        } else {
            s = 4;
        }
        if (keysDown.contains(KeyEvent.VK_UP) /*|| keysDown.contains(KeyEvent.VK_W)*/){
            scaleChange = true;
            moverY += 10;
        }
        if (keysDown.contains(KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) /*|| keysDown.contains(KeyEvent.VK_D)*/){
            if (!moving) {
                Player.move(1,s);
                right = true;
            } else {
                moverX -= 10;
            }
        }
        if (keysDown.contains(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) /*|| keysDown.contains(KeyEvent.VK_S)*/){
            scaleChange = true;
            moverY -= 10;
        }
        if (keysDown.contains(KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) /*|| keysDown.contains(KeyEvent.VK_A)*/){
            if (!moving) {
                Player.move(3,s);
                right = false;
            } else {
                moverX += 10;
            }
            
        }
        if (keysDown.contains(KeyEvent.VK_E)){
            databaseConnector(true);
        }
        if (keysDown.contains(KeyEvent.VK_SPACE)){
            Player.ha = 0;
            Player.va = 0;
            Player.vSpeed = 0;
            Player.hSpeed = 0;
            if (!moving){
                modulus[0] = mod1.getValue();
                modulus[1] = mod2.getValue();
                natural[0] = len1.getValue();
                natural[0] /= 10;
                natural[1] = len2.getValue();
                natural[1] /= 10;
                setRectangles();
                startPosition = (int) (Player.getCenterX() - rect.get(0).getMaxX());
            }
            moving = !moving;
        }
        if (keysDown.contains(KeyEvent.VK_EQUALS)){
            scaleScreen += 1;
            scaleChange = true;
        }
        if (keysDown.contains(KeyEvent.VK_SLASH)){
            scaleScreen -= 1;
            if(scaleScreen == 0){
                scaleScreen = 1;
            }                
        }
    }
    
    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
                   
    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        if (!keysDown.contains(e.getKeyCode())){
           keysDown.add(e.getKeyCode()); 
        }
        action();
        //throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        keysDown.remove(new Integer(e.getKeyCode()));
    }
    
}
```

Comment: The problem has nothing to do with JDBC, so I removed the tag. I find your handling of key events rather curious (why not just handle it in `keyTyped` or `keyPressed`?), but I haven't done anything with Swing for a while. If I had to guess, the `keyReleased` event never gets processed, so the `VK_E` remains in the `keysDown` collection.

Comment: I thought that may be the problem, so I tried to manually have it remove if it exists, when the ` VK_E ` but that seemed to just cause a crash. Honestly, I have had loads of problems trying to get ` keyListeners` working, and this method just seems to be working. Finally, I did not think it was an issue with the jdbc, but I have never had a problem like this before, and being my first time using jdbc, I thought it may be relevant (not sure though).